# Import JSON files using script to SQL Table

Tags: json, sql-server

I'm trying to import multiple JSON files using a script to be inserted into SQL Table, the format of the JSON as the following example:

```json
[
  {
    "eventSubmissionTime": 1595235794804,
    "correlationId": "gems;shipmentRef=204055527;gemsId=6422676195;GATE-OUTEXPY;integrationId=941343283",
    "eventName": "Actual gate out",
    "senderOrgName": "Maersk",
    "senderOrgTypes": [
      "ocean carrier"
    ],
    "originatorId": "MAEU",
    "eventOccurrenceTime": 1595234100000,
    "eventOccurrenceTime8601": "2020-07-20T11:35:00+03:00",
    "originatorName": "Maersk Line",
    "vehicleId": "JOMERC",
    "transportationPhase": "Export",
    "eventTransactionId": "4b73ccd8-b202-4827-bcd7-4d7074efcb0e",
    "carrierBookingNumber": "204055527",
    "terminal": "JOZRC01",
    "transportEquipmentId": "75e47f1f-1164-4f48-9097-3525c64924e6",
    "equipmentNumber": "MRSU3607627",
    "subscriptionId": "53e1e15d-e9cc-4a81-9814-57fb7643fb6c",
    "fullStatus": "Empty",
    "eventType": "actualGateOut",
    "associatedConsignmentIds": [],
    "associatedCarrierBookingNumbers": [],
    "location": {
      "type": "UN/Locode",
      "value": "JOAMM"
    },
    "messages": [
      "common.event.status.success"
    ],
    "sentFromInternal": false,
    "eventPriority": 5
  }
]
```

and I'm using the following SQL code to import the files:

```sql
DECLARE 
   @SQL Varchar(200),
   @file Varchar(100),
   @Subdirectory varchar(50)

DECLARE 
   @files table (Subdirectory Varchar(50),depth int,[file] int)

Insert into @files execute master.dbo.xp_DirTree 'D:\TradeLens',1,1
--Insert into @files execute master.dbo.xp_DirTree '\\127.0.0.1\d$\TradeLens',1,1

--select * from @files

DECLARE Cur_FileName Cursor FOR Select Subdirectory from @files
Open Cur_FileName
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_FileName INTO @Subdirectory

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   SET @file = '''D:\TradeLens\'+ @Subdirectory + '''';
   --Select @file
   --SET @SQL= 'INSERT INTO Jtable1 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '+@file+', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e'
   SET @SQL= 'INSERT INTO JTable SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '+@file+', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e'

   PRINT @SQL
   EXEC (@SQL)

   FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_FileName INTO @Subdirectory
END 
Close Cur_FileName
DEALLOCATE Cur_FileName
```

I'm facing now the following error:

> INSERT INTO Aseel2 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK
> 'D:\TradeLens\20200720020538.json', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e Msg 213, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 1 Column name or number of supplied values does not
> match table definition.
>
> INSERT INTO Aseel2 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK
> 'D:\TradeLens\20200720020716.json', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e Msg 213, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 1 Column name or number of supplied values does not
> match table definition.
>
> INSERT INTO Aseel2 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK
> 'D:\TradeLens\20200720020717.json', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e Msg 213, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 1 Column name or number of supplied values does not
> match table definition.
>
> INSERT INTO Aseel2 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK
> 'D:\TradeLens\20200720020718.json', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e Msg 213, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 1 Column name or number of supplied values does not
> match table definition.
>
> INSERT INTO Aseel2 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK
> 'D:\TradeLens\20200720020722.json', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e Msg 213, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 1 Column name or number of supplied values does not
> match table definition.
>
> INSERT INTO Aseel2 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK
> 'D:\TradeLens\20200720020723.json', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e Msg 213, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 1 Column name or number of supplied values does not
> match table definition.
>
> INSERT INTO Aseel2 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK
> 'D:\TradeLens\20200720020726.json', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e Msg 213, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 1 Column name or number of supplied values does not
> match table definition.
>
> INSERT INTO Aseel2 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK
> 'D:\TradeLens\20200720020727.json', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e Msg 213, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 1 Column name or number of supplied values does not
> match table definition.
>
> INSERT INTO Aseel2 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK
> 'D:\TradeLens\20200720020729.json', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e Msg 213, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 1 Column name or number of supplied values does not
> match table definition.
>
> INSERT INTO Aseel2 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK
> 'D:\TradeLens\20200720020732.json', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e Msg 213, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 1 Column name or number of supplied values does not
> match table definition.
>
> INSERT INTO Aseel2 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK
> 'D:\TradeLens\20200720020733.json', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e Msg 213, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 1 Column name or number of supplied values does not
> match table definition.
>
> Completion time: 2020-07-23T09:41:45.0250136+03:00

My problem is that I'm not able to create the correct SQL table structure even I used online convert tools from JSON to SQL, so the question how I can insert the data in the SQL table with avoiding the unmatched structure issue.

Comment: You need to change the statement - `SET @SQL= 'INSERT INTO JTable (JColumn) SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '+@file+', SINGLE_CLOB ) AS e'`. This is a possible solution for this `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition` error. But, if you want to parse the content of the stored JSON, you need to use `OPENJSON()`.

Comment: still need help , how to parse the content of the stored JSON using OPENJSON()  ... can you update the script  ?

Comment: You mean the JSON, stored in the `JTable`?

Comment: yes i mean the JSON, stored in the JTable